# Why does getRequestUrl() return StringBuffer instead of String?

Tags: java, string, servlets

request.getRequestUri() returns a String.

request.getRequestURL() returns a StringBuffer.

I can understand the reason that Requests.Util's requestURL() use StringBuffer for making String.

However, I can't understand why that method return StringBuffer not String.

Why..?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The JavaDoc of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) says

> Because this method returns a `StringBuffer`, not a string, you can modify the URL easily, for example, to append query parameters.

This seems to be their motivation for this specific type.

Personally I don't think this kind of micro-optimization is worth the headache. Especially since `StringBuffer` has been all but replaced by `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I concur. String's are immutable and they are allowing you to mutate the URL if you so wish, but for most cases, this is probably a bit over-engineered.

Comment: I suspect the reasoning was something along the line "we already use a `StringBuffer` to reconstruct the URL and a common use case of that method is to modify the result to produce a new URL, so why not skip the conversion to String and back and return the `StringBuffer` immediately".

Comment: I agree. Ultimately, the implementing class can perform the conversion to a String object if they so desire. StringBuffer does maintain more flexibility.

Comment: Probably relevant to mention the year as well when this was designed: 1995. It started off as static utility method `HttpUtils#getRequestURL(HttpServletRequest)` and then was moved into `HttpServletRequest` as instance method since Servlet 2.1 in 1998. In other words, the real answer boils down to "it's just legacy".